# Помогите разобраться с JList

Tags: java, база-данных, swing

Создал компонент Jlist и создаю таблицу для БД, заношу значение для БД в список. Всё работает, но проблема в том что когда я, к примеру, возвращаюсь в предыдущее окно или закрываю программу то весь список исчезает. И таблица такая создана, но в компоненте Jlist пусто. Как сделать так что бы значения оставались в компоненте.

```
private JList list4;
final DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();

ArrayList <String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

public Options(final DBConnection connect) {
    setContentPane(panel1);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,600));
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int sizeWidth = 600;
    int sizeHeight = 600;
    int locationX = (screenSize.width - sizeWidth) / 2;
    int locationY = (screenSize.height - sizeHeight) / 2;
    setBounds(locationX, locationY, sizeWidth, sizeHeight);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    list4.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);

    list4.setModel(listModel);

    DBConnection.rs = query("SELECT * from Groups");

    try {

        while (rs.next()) {
            String predmetu = rs.getString("Gruppu");
            comboBox1.addItem(predmetu);
        }
        DBConnection.rs = query("SELECT * from PR");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String predmetu = rs.getString("predmet_PR");
            comboBox2.addItem(predmetu);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // переход к новому окну
    создатьНовуюЗаписьButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String vuborGroups = (String) comboBox1.getSelectedItem();
            String vuborPredmets = (String) comboBox2.getSelectedItem();
            String nametable = vuborGroups + vuborPredmets;
            String createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + nametable + "(id int(100) NOT NULL auto_increment, PRIMARY KEY (id))";
            updateQuery(createTableSQL);

            updateQuery("ALTER TABLE " + nametable + " ADD students varchar(100) NOT NULL");

            try {

                DBConnection.rs = connect.query("SELECT * from " + vuborGroups);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String students = rs.getString("student");
                    list1.add(students);
                    System.out.println("Student " +students);
                }

                for(int i = 0; i< list1.size(); i++)
                {
                    String stud = list1.get(i);
                    updateQuery("INSERT INTO " + nametable + " (students)VALUES('" + stud + "')");
                    System.out.println (list1.get(i));
                }
                listModel.addElement(nametable);
            }
                catch( Exception r)
                {r.printStackTrace();}
            new CreateJournal(nametable);
            System.out.println("Таблица созданна!");
        }
    });
}
```